# Lightning component get user's language rather than user's locale

Tags: lightning-aura-components, label, locale

I have a few labels I use on my Lightning Components. They are all based on the user's locale but nothing changes when user's language changes.

How can I change this ? My users never change locale parameter but only language field.

Thank you

Comment: Is it Custom Labels ?

Comment: Yep they are custom labels.

Comment: It should be working. Are you using something like {!$Label.c.MyLabel} ?

Comment: Yes I am. It works when the user change his locale but not if he changes his Language. That is the point.. They want to change it rather than locale..

Comment: That's really strange, I tried changing my language and it works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's taking your company's default language/locale.

Not sure about it, but I found this :
"Click on Setup | Administration Setup | Company Profile | Company Information | Edit and change the Default Language, Default Locale, and Currency Locale. All new users will inherit these Language and Locale settings."

Answer (score 0):

I found something else : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYHKQA4

Try a hard refresh, Ctrl+Shift+R .